# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' despide the same code working elsewhere?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have code which retrieves users from firebase. The problem is that I get the error:

> Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

On the lines, I marked in the block below. The weird thing is that the exact same code is currently in another project in nearly identical circumstances and it does not get this error.

The code is below:

```
    func retriveUsers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("user2").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.users.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {//Error
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String {//Error
                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        self.users.append(userToShow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    print(users.count, " This is the number of users retrived the first looks like: ", users[0].userID)
}
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278649/ambiguous-use-of-subscript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915840/ambiguous-use-of-subscript) and neiother has solved my problem. **What is the solution here?**

Comment: Can you share one other place where it worked?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, what would you like me to share? It is the same block of code only in a different class.

Comment: You don't name a class property with a white space letter.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the type of `value` in `users`, you provided `AnyObject` which is ambiguous because it can be both an array (index subscripted) or dictionary (key subscripted).

Be more specific and tell the compiler that `value` is a dictionary, by the way it's always supposed to be `Any` not `AnyObject` and check the type safely

```
if let users = snapshot.value as? [String : [String:Any]] { ...
```

Comment: Using forced casts is a bad idea, especially if the cast happens on data received from a server...

Comment: @Cristik **You** are responsible for the database. You ought to know the type of **your** data

Comment: That until the DB management role is passed to someone else :) Regardless you own or not the database, future changes in its layout will lead to crashes all over the app, with this approach.

Comment: And BTW, that argument like, "you own the gun, you are responsible if you shoot yourself in the foot", doesn't quite hold if you have the opportunity of adding some extra safety to the gun which makes it harder to go off.

Comment: I am getting: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1f0649f58) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1f0649bc0).
when running

Comment: Then you have to check the type to handle the `null` case.